# I am trying to write a query but can seem to think of a way to do it

Tags: sql

Hello In the SQL Database dbo.Fee I have

```
-----------------------------------------
Id       | CaseId   | FeeType | UnitCost
-----------------------------------------
1017796  | 2697789  |      29 |       50 
1018167  | 2697789  |       1 |      150 
1019493  | 2697789  |      15 |       30
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to write a sql query where I want it displayed as

```
-----------------------------------------
CaseId   | AdminFee  | SubFee  | ContFee
-----------------------------------------
2697789  |       50  |    150  |     30
-----------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do some sort of pivot. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: What is the relationship between the input and output? You don't actually describe what you are trying to do anywhere...

Comment: You really couldn't come up with a better question title, then what you posted?  That doesn't explain at all what you are trying to do. Also, where are you getting the names `AdminFee`, `SubFee`, `ContFee`, we aren't going to guess these things.  If you've got a table with these names stored **then post those details**.

Comment: Is there a table that defines FeeType values and names?  Is there a rationale behind the ordering of the columns in the result (it isn't FeeType ordered by number or by mapped name)?  Are there just the three FeeTypes ever, or can there be others?

Comment: Just join the table with itself for the other values you want.

Comment: The FeeType have a mapped name where 1=SubsequentFee, 23=AdminFee and 12=ContractorFee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example query that returns the specified result:

```
SELECT f.CaseId
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType = 29 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS AdminFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType =  1 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS SubFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType = 15 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS ContFee
  FROM dbo.Fee f
 GROUP BY f.CaseId
```

---

The query in this answer makes several assumptions, some of which are likely to be wrong. For example, it assumes that the `FeeType` column in the `dbo.Fee` table is integer datatype.

Doing equality comparisons with FLOAT datatype can be problematic, because that's an approximation of a decimal value.

For the `FeeType` column, which appears to be a discrete integer value, we'd usually use an integer datatype, rather than an IEEE FLOAT.

For a "cost" value, we'd typically use a DECIMAL datatype, or in SQL Server, we could use the MONEY datatype,  , rather than an IEEE FLOAT.

Equality comparison on the FLOAT type can be problemtaic... the only good way to do that is to figure out much of a difference you'd allow between a FLOAT approximation and an integer or decimal value, and still consider them to be "equal".

Here's one approach to doing comparisons with FLOAT, allowing up to a .01 difference in values...

```
SELECT f.CaseId
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType > 28.99 AND f.feeType < 29.01 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS AdminFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType >  0.99 AND f.feeType <  1.01 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS SubFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType > 14.99 AND f.feeType < 15.01 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS ContFee
  FROM dbo.Fee f
 GROUP BY f.CaseId
```

A much better fix would be to change the datatype of `FeeType` column to INTEGER type.

To also return "AdminFee plus SubFee", just add another SUM(expression) to the SELECT list; this expression would return UnitCost if FeeType was 29 OR 1.

```
SELECT f.CaseId
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType > 28.99 AND f.feeType < 29.01 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS AdminFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType >  0.99 AND f.feeType <  1.01 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS SubFee
     , SUM(CASE WHEN f.FeeType > 14.99 AND f.feeType < 15.01 THEN f.UnitCost END) AS ContFee
     , SUM(CASE 
            WHEN ( f.FeeType > 28.99 AND f.feeType < 29.01 )
              OR ( f.FeeType >  0.99 AND f.feeType <  1.01 ) THEN f.UnitCost END) AS AdminPlusSub
  FROM dbo.Fee f
 GROUP BY f.CaseId
```

Comment: Don't edit questions to add a solution to them.

Comment: @SavioDias: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! Likely, you have additional requirements that are not satisfied by my example query. But rather than guess at what those requirements are (e.g. additional fee types), a total of all UnitCost for the case, etc.

Comment: -----------------------------------------
CaseId   | AdminFee  | SubFee  | ContFee
-----------------------------------------
2697789  |     NULL  |    150  |    NULL
-----------------------------------------

Comment: @SavioDias: The default return from a CASE expression is NULL (i.e. ELSE NULL). It appears that the condition `FeeType=29` is not satisfied by any rows. Perhaps my guess at the datatype and content of the FeeType column is wrong; I'd assumed it was an integer value.  The conditional test following WHEN can be modified; the intent is to get a TRUE value for a row we want UnitCost returned from.

Comment: The FeeType and the UnitCost which is also the TotalCost is  a Float value and its not null

Comment: What if I want to calculate the total of AdminFee and SubFee where do I put that in the select statement. Do I need to declare a new variable or is there another way of doing it within the query?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using MS SQL Server this might be wgat you want.

```
select 
  caseid, 
  max(adminfee) AS AdminFee, 
  max(subfee) as Subfee, 
  max(contfee) as ContFee
from (
  select 
    caseid, 
    case when FeeType = 29 Then UnitCost End as AdminFee,
    case when FeeType = 1 Then UnitCost End as SubFee,
    case when FeeType = 15 Then UnitCost End as ContFee
  from dbo.fee
) a 
group by caseid
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82336/1)

Comment: Curious about MAX vs SUM?  Most institutions are happy to charge multiple fees and add them up.  Otherwise, well done.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point. I just choose max as I thought there would only be one fee of each kind for a specific caseid. Looking at the answer by spencer7593 I realize that sum might have been more appropriate and eliminated the need to use max to avoid null values.

Comment: the out put is displaying |2697789  |     NULL  |    150  |    NULL|

Comment: @SavioDias Is it? It's working in the fiddle I supplied, but maybe my assumption about data types is wrong.

Comment: The FeeType and the UnitCost which is also the TotalCost is a Float value and its not null

Comment: @SavioDias In your example data the FeeTypes are AdminFee=29, SubFee=1 and ContFee=15; in your comment above you say it's 1=SubsequentFee, 23=AdminFee and 12=ContractorFee. My answer presumed the former. If you want it to work with the latter set of values you just have to change the values used in the case expression.